# Together Everyone Achieves More

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

*(related: [one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19912/acrostic-poem-programming), [two](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7105/create-an-acrostic), [three](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4422/acrostic-polyglot-programming))*

An [acrostic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acrostic) is a style of poem/writing where the beginning character of each line, when read vertically, also produces a word or message. For example,

```
Together
Everyone
Achieves
More
```

also spells out the word `TEAM` when the first column is read vertically.

Acrostics are a subset of [mesostic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesostic)s, where the vertical word can be anywhere in the horizontal words. For example, the `TEAM` one above could also be written as a mesostic as follows

```
   togeTher
everyonE
       Achieves
       More
```

along with several other variations.

The challenge here will be to produce an acrostic or mesostic from a given list of input words.

#### Input

- A list of words in any [any suitable format](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- The list will only contain words made from lowercase `[a-z]`.
- The list is guaranteed to form an acrostic or a mesostic (no need to handle bogus input).
- One of the words in the input will form the vertical word, while the rest make the horizontal words - part of the challenge here is to find the appropriate vertical word, so it *cannot* be taken separately.

#### Output

- The ASCII-art acrostic or mesostic formed from the input words, written to STDOUT or returned, in any reasonable format.
- The corresponding vertical word must be capitalized (as in the examples).
- Leading spaces to get the vertical word to line up appropriately are **required**. Trailing spaces, and leading/trailing newlines are optional. *Extra* leading spaces are fine as well, so long as the words align correctly.
- If *both* an acrostic and mesostic are possible, output *only* the acrostic.
- If more than one acrostic/mesostic is possible, your code can output any or all of them.

#### Rules

- Either a full program or a function are acceptable.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

#### Examples

```
['together', 'team', 'everyone', 'achieves', 'more']
Together
Everyone
Achieves
More

['aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa']
Aaa
Aaa
Aaa
# One output, or multiple (of the same) output is allowed

['aaa', 'aaa', 'aab', 'baa']
Aaa
Aaa
Baa
# This is the only allowed output, since others would be mesostic, which are lower priority

['live', 'every', 'love', 'very', 'ohio']
Live
Ohio
Very
Every
# Note that 'live' couldn't be the vertical word since then it would be a mesostic, which is lower priority output

['cow', 'of', 'fox']
cOw
 Fox
# A shorter mesostic test case

['late', 'ballroom', 'anvil', 'to', 'head']
anviL
   bAllroom
    To
   hEad
```

Comment: It seems that in the cases where an acrostic is produced, the list will be in that order?

Comment: Can you have a shorter mesostic testcase?

Comment: Are extra leading spaces allowed?

Comment: It doesn't say that the input is guaranteed to be sorted correctly, but judging from the test cases, they are. Are they?

Comment: @aross They aren't (e.g. the `live ohio very every` test case, or the last one).

Comment: Dear god. I'll pass then

Comment: @Pietu1998 Sure, that's fine -- the important thing is that the words are lined up. I'll edit in that clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>52</s> <s>49</s> <s>47</s> 46 bytes

```
jm++*;-lsQhAd<HGr>HG4hhMDfhhShMTm.b,xNYNtdhd.p
```

[Try it online.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jm%2B%2B%2a%3B-lsQhAd%3CHGr%3EHG4hhMDfhhShMTm.b%2CxNYNtdhd.p&input=%5B%22late%22%2C+%22ballroom%22%2C+%22anvil%22%2C+%22to%22%2C+%22head%22%5D&debug=0)

This is probably very golfable. It prints a bunch of leading spaces.

Answer (score 6):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 145 bytes

```
p~c[A:B:C],Bl1,A:CcP@pz:cahgB,P:1a~@nw|lL,?:laot:" "rjg:Ljb:sa:?z:cap~c[A:B:C],Bl1,A:Cc@pz:caZ:LmgB,Zl-yM,Z:M:Lz:2az:ca~@nw
bB,?h@u:Bc
b#=,?h@u|h
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=cH5jW0E6QjpDXSxCbDEsQTpDY1BAcHo6Y2FoZ0IsUDoxYX5Abnd8bEwsPzpsYW90OiIgInJqZzpMamI6c2E6P3o6Y2FwfmNbQTpCOkNdLEJsMSxBOkNjQHB6OmNhWjpMbWdCLFpsLXlNLFo6TTpMejoyYXo6Y2F-QG53CmJCLD9oQHU6QmMKYiM9LD9oQHV8aA&input=WyJjb3ciOiJvZiI6ImZveCJd&debug=on)

(Takes half a minute, so be patient.)

Comment: Looks like this took some effort to write :) Very nice!

Comment: @TimmyD Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 255 <s>263 269 286</s>

*Edit* 17 bytes saved as arbitrary number of leading spaces is allowed
*Edit2* some shuffling, 6 byte saved
*Edit3* return a list of string instead of a single string with newlines (OP comment to feersum's answer), 8 more bytes saved

For each word in the input list, I use a recursive DFS to find all possibile mesostics/acrostics. Each one is stored as an array with word and target letter position inside the word. Every result found is saved in global result array at position 1 (if it's an acrostic) or 0 if it's a mesostic.

After the complete scan for all words, I get the result at last position in array and build and return its ascii art rapresentation.

```js
l=>(l.map((w,i)=>(r=(p,v,i,a)=>(l[i]='.',w[p]?l.map((v,i)=>~(j=v.search(w[p]))&&r(p+1,v,i,a|j,m[p]=[j,v])):l[p+1]?0:s[+!a]=[...m],l[i]=v))(0,w,i,m=[]),s=[]),m=s.pop(),m.map(([j,v])=>' '.repeat((l+0).length-j)+v.slice(0,j)+v[j].toUpperCase()+v.slice(j+1)))
```

*Less golfed*

```js
f=l=>(
  l.map((w,i)=>
    // r: recursive DFS function
    // defined here as it uses local w variable
    (r = (p,v,i,a) => (
     l[i] = '.'
     , w[p] 
     ? l.map(
       (v,i) => ~(j=v.search(w[p])) && 
                r(p+1, v, i, a|j, m[p] = [j,v])
       
     )
     : l[p+1] ? 0 // invalid if there are still unused words
              : s[+!a]=[...m] // a is 0 if acrostic
     , l[i] = v) 
    )(0, w, i, m=[])
  , s=[]),
  m = s.pop(), // get last result
  // m.map(([j]) => o = o<j ? j : o, o=0), // find offset for alignment
  // no need to find the optimal offset as leading blanks are allowed
  m.map(([j,v]) => ' '.repeat((l+0).length-j) 
                   + v.slice(0,j) 
                   + v[j].toUpperCase()
                   + v.slice(j+1)
  )
)
```

**Test**

```js
f=l=>(l.map((w,i)=>(r=(p,v,i,a)=>(l[i]='.',w[p]?l.map((v,i)=>~(j=v.search(w[p]))&&r(p+1,v,i,a|j,m[p]=[j,v])):l[p+1]?0:s[+!a]=[...m],l[i]=v))(0,w,i,m=[]),s=[]),m=s.pop(),m.map(([j,v])=>' '.repeat((l+0).length-j)+v.slice(0,j)+v[j].toUpperCase()+v.slice(j+1)))

console.log=x=>O.textContent+=x+'\n\n'

;[
 ['together', 'team', 'everyone', 'achieves', 'more']
,['aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa']
,['aaa', 'aaa', 'aab', 'baa']
,['live', 'every', 'love', 'very', 'ohio']
,['cow', 'of', 'fox']
,['late', 'ballroom', 'anvil', 'to', 'head']
].forEach(l=>console.log(f(l).join`\n`))
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica 10.0, 139 bytes

An unnamed function returning a list of lines:

```
Sort[{q=Max[p=Min/@Position@@@({z={##2},#})],Array[" "&,q-#2]<>ToUpperCase~MapAt~##&@@@({z,p})}&@@@Permutations@Characters@#][[1,2]]&
```

Example usage:

```
In[144]:= f = Sort[{q=Max[p=Min/@Position@@@({z={##2},#})],Array[" "&,q-#2]ToUpperCase~MapAt~##&@@@({z,p})}&@@@Permutations@Characters@#][[1,2]]&;

In[145]:= f @ {"late","ballroom","anvil","to","head"} // Column

 ... several pages of warnings ... 

Out[145]= baLlroom
            Anvil
            To
           hEad
```

<s>I'm looking for suggestions on better ways to do the capitalization.</s> I found a very nice function `MapAt` for capitalizing the letter in the string.

Comment: Sure, functions can return multiline strings as a list of strings.

Answer (score 3):

### Perl6, <s>287</s> <s>277</s> 269 bytes

```
my @w=$*IN.words;my ($q,$r)=gather for ^@w {my @v=@w.rotate($_);my \d=@v.shift;for @v.permutations {my @o=flat($_ Z d.comb).map:{$^a.index: $^b};take $_,@o if @o>>.defined.all}}.sort(*[1].sum)[0];for @$q Z @$r ->(\a,\b){say " "x($r.max -b)~a.substr(0,b)~a.substr(b).tc}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, <s>214</s> <s>206</s> <s>204</s> 202 bytes

```
import Data.List
z=zipWith
h i j t|(u,v:w)<-splitAt j t=([1..sum i-j]>>" ")++u++toEnum(fromEnum v-32):w
f x=uncurry(z=<<h)$sort[(head<$>z elemIndices w l,l)|w:l<-permutations x,(True<$w)==z elem w l]!!0
```

Returns a list of space padded strings, e.g. `f ["late","ballroom","anvil","to","head"]` -> `[" baLlroom","   Anvil","   To","  hEad"]` or more display friendly:

```
*Main> mapM_ putStrLn $ f ["late", "ballroom", "anvil", "to", "head"]
 baLlroom
   Anvil
   To
  hEad
```

`f` selects the words that are written horizontally together with a list of offsets. `h` pads each word according to the corresponding offset and inserts the uppercase letter. In detail:

```
                permutations x       -- for each permutation of the input list x
         w:l<-                       -- bind w to the first word and l to the rest
             (True<$w)==z elem w l   -- keep it if the list of other words
                                     -- containing the next letter of w
                                     -- equals (length w) times True, i.e. we have
                                     -- as many matching letters as letters in w.
                                     -- This rules out combinations shortcut by zipWith

                                     -- for all the remaining w and l make a pair
         head<$>z elemIndices w l    -- the first element of the list of list of
                                     -- indices where the letter appears in the word 
                                l    -- and l itself
   sort                              -- sort the pairs (all 0 indices, i.e. acrostics
                                     -- go first)
                               !!0   -- pick the first
                                     -- now we have a pair like
                                     -- ([2,0,0,1],["ballroom","anvil","to","head"])
 uncurry(z=<<h)                      -- loop over (index,word) and 
                                     -- provide the third parameter for h 



 h i j t                             -- h takes the list of indices and
                                     -- an index j and a word t
       (u,v:w)<-splitAt j t          -- split the word at the index and bind
                                     --   u: part before the split
                                     --   v: letter at the split
                                     --   w: part after the split
         [1..sum i-j]>>" "           -- the spaces to pad
           ++ u                      -- followed by u
           ++ toEnum(fromEnum v-32)  -- and uppercase v
           :                         -- and w
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 249 bytes

Probably still very golfable

```python
from itertools import*;e=enumerate;lambda l:[[[' ']*(max(j for k,(j,c)in o[1:])-i)+l[k][:i]+[c.upper()]+l[k][i+1:]for k,(i,c)in o[1:]]for p in product(*[list(e(w))for w in l])for o in permutations(list(e(p)))if[c for k,(i,c)in o[1:]]==l[o[0][0]]][0]
```

Takes and returns a list of list of characters.
- e.g. `"   bAllroom"` is `[' ',' ',' ','b','A','l','l','r','o','o','m']`

Only ever returns the first result and checks in an order such that all the acrostics are checked first.

See all test cases printed in the display format on [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/KNWvvV)

---

Here is a more readable functional form that does the same (except it returns the first result immediately rather than evaluating and then returning the first result):

```python
from itertools import*
def f(l):
    for p in product(*[list(enumerate(w)) for w in l]):
        for o in permutations(list(enumerate(p))):
            if [c for k,(i,c) in o[1:]] == l[o[0][0]]:
                return [ [' '] * (max(j for k,(j,c) in o[1:]) - i)
                       + l[k][:i]
                       + [c.upper()]
                       + l[k][i+1:]
                       for k, (i, c) in o[1:]
                       ]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 6, 177 bytes

```perl6
->\a{for first({.[0] eq[~] .[1]»[1]},map |*,[Z] map {.[0]X [X] map {.comb[(^$_,$_,$_^..* for ^.chars)]},.[1..*]},a.permutations)[1] ->$/ {say [~] " "x a.comb-$0,|$0,$1.uc,|$2}}
```

Brute-force solution.

#### How it works

```perl6
-> \a {
    for first({.[0] eq[~] .[1]»[1]},          # For the first valid candidate
            map |*, [Z]                       # among the transposed
            map {                             # lists of candidates
                .[0] X [X] map {
                    .comb[(^$_,$_,$_^..* for ^.chars)]
                }, .[1..*]
            },
            a.permutations                    # for all permutations of the input:
        )[1] ->$/ {
        say [~] " "x a.comb-$0,|$0,$1.uc,|$2  # Print the candidate as ASCII art.
    }
}
```

Each candidate looks like:

```perl6
"of", (("c"),"o",("w")), ((),"f",("o","x"))
```

Transposing the list of lists of candidates is necessary to ensure that an acrostic, if it exists, is found before any mesostic.