# Find a recursive acronym

Tags: code-golf, string

## Introduction

A [recursive acronym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_acronym) is an acronym that contains or refers to itself, for example:
`Fish` could be a recursive acronym for `Fish is shiny hero`, notice how that also contains the acronym itself. Another example is `Hi` -> `Hi igloo`. Or even `ppcg paints` -> `ppcg paints cool galaxies pouring acid into night time stars`

So basically, a sentence is a recursive acronym if the first letters of each of the words spell out the first word or words.

---

## Challenge

Make a program that takes a string of 1 or more words separated by a space character, and outputs a recursive acronym, or an empty string if it's impossible. It is impossible to make a recursive acronym for a string like, for example, `ppcg elephant` because you would start by taking the `p` from `ppcg` then adding that to the acronym, then taking the `e` from `elephant`. But now we have a contradiction, since the acronym currently spells out "pe..", which conflicts with "pp..". That's also the case with, for example, `hi`. You would take the `h` from `hi`, but the sentence is now over and there are no more letters to spell out `hi` and we are just left with `h` which doesn't match `hi`. (The string needs an amount of words more than or equal to the amount of letters in the acronym)

Input and output are not case sensitive

---

## Restrictions

- Anything inputted into your program will be valid English words. But you must make sure to output valid English words too (you can use a database or just store a word for each of the 26 letters)
- Standard loopholes and default IO rules apply

---

## Test Cases

```
hi igloo -> hi
ppcg paints -> (impossible)
ppcg paints cool giraffes -> ppcg
ppcg paints cool galaxies pouring acid into night time stars -> ppcgpaints
ppcg paints cool galaxies pouring acid into night time -> ppcg
ppcg questions professional pool challengers greatly -> (impossible)
I -> I
```

---

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the smallest source code in bytes wins

Comment: [Partially related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/90957/42963).

Comment: What's valid English? Is `gat` one?

Comment: @l4m2 Anything that's found in a dictionary, I wont be too strict about that rule

Comment: @FireCubez So as https://www.dictionary.com/browse/dat?s=ts, `aat` is not allowed and `dat` is fine?

Comment: @l4m2 Yes, I only included that rule to prevent answers where the "word" is a single letter

Comment: @FireCubez but single letter exist in lots of dictionary

Comment: @l4m2 But not all letters have single-letter words, only ones I can think of are `I` and `a`

Comment: Q, q
[kyoo]
noun, plural Q's or Qs, q's or qs.

    the 17th letter of the English alphabet, a consonant.
    any spoken sound represented by the letter Q or q, as in quick, acquit, or Iraq.
    something having the shape of a Q.

Comment: Also I don't think ppcg is a word in dictionary

Comment: For `ppcg paints cool galaxies paints air in not the sea` should the acronym actually include space, as in `ppcg paints`? As I see, most answers don't and simply output `ppcgpaints`.

Comment: @KirillL. Yeah, that's fine

Comment: Would it be possible to add these or similar test cases: `ppcg paints cool galaxies pouring acid into night time` (acronym matches only part of the second word) and `ppcg questions professional pool challengers greatly` (acronym contains a valid string, but has additional characters)

Comment: @KamilDrakari Added

Comment: Okay, one of those test cases didn't turn out as I expected. Just to make sure neither of us is making a mistake `ppcg paints cool galaxies pouring acid into night time` would be "ppcgpaint" when made into an acronym, but the output should be `ppcg` even though it's only a partial match?

Comment: @KamilDrakari "ppcgpaint" is a partial match of "ppcgpaints", so we have to fall back to "ppcg" which is a full match

Comment: I don´t really get the difference between the two choices.

Comment: As all current solutions are taking the first option ("find acronym"), and the "find sentence" option is much more complicated (so no way of being competitive with the first one – you need some word list, to start with), I would suggest to remove it from this challenge and make it its own question.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Alright, I removed it

Comment: What about `ppcg paints cool galaxies pouring acid into night pay`?

Comment: @l4m2 impossible since it would match `ppcg paintp` not `ppcg paints`

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 13 bytes

```
¸
mÎ¬
VøUÎ ©V
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcsxCgIxEEbhPqf4Sa0HsRXcRiyGmM2OJJmQRPAUew/BA2ydHCyKpWD5@Hg3SnWMtqnQ1/ZSU99OfUV7TmOc9cJg50X0TumUjEMijrX8JIyIh@NM82z/IHl6sC1Ics8cHcjwFR8XRHZLReVgUSrl73/QF@zD8Q0)

Comment: [11 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=uAptzqwKzrZWqVY=&input=InBwY2cgZWxlcGhhbnQi)

Comment: This fails on the `ppcg paints cool galaxies pouring acid into night time stars` test case

Comment: [here](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=uAptzqwK5UAoWCtTK1kgeDJ9IGZfZVMgPT09Vg==&input=InBwY2cgcGFpbnRzIGNvb2wgZ2FsYXhpZXMgcG91cmluZyBhY2lkIGludG8gbmlnaHQgdGltZSBzdGFycyIKLVE=)'s a version that works for that test case, but it's not golfed

Comment: My previous 13 bytes solution was correct Dx\

Comment: The current version just checks that the acronym contains the first word, which results in [some new issues](https://tio.run/##JYxNCsIwEEb3OcWQtR7ErWA34mKI43QkfyZTsJfoPQQP0HV7sBhw98F773ti1ta21YR92b5m2NfLvsD2GVq72pwdQ04hEBeMogQuJQ@MHt9CtaOpSGRAJ3eQqAmi8KigEsgezL9/TVRVUux6SQ@qtW/0ve1PbkTvKTKVClwI1c/W2JO9wTGcfw)

Comment: [Here](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=uAptzuUrIGZV5SspzA==&input=WyJoaSBpZ2xvbyIsCiJwcGNnIHBhaW50cyIsCiJwcGNnIHBhaW50cyBjb29sIGdpcmFmZmVzIiwKInBwY2cgcGFpbnRzIGNvb2wgZ2FsYXhpZXMgcG91cmluZyBhY2lkIGludG8gbmlnaHQgdGltZSBzdGFycyIsCiJwcGNnIHBvbW1lZ3Jhbml0ZSBjb29sIGdhbGF4aWVzIHBvdXJpbmcgYWNpZCBpbnRvIG5pZ2h0IHRpbWUiLAoicHBjZyBxdWVzdGlvbnMgcHJvZmVzc2lvbmFsIHBvb2wgY2hhbGxlbmdlcnMgZ3JlYXRseSIsCiJJIl0gLW1S)'s a version which works on the new test cases

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 16 bytes

```
ð¡©ηʒJ®€нJηså}θJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY4xCsIwFIZ3T/HorFfwAL3FM6bpg5gXk1Qs6OIRvIGDgyDiVhcpNJtD8QxepAZcHJzcfvj@7@dnjzOSw2ZVD/HaHbpT3zz2eXd57c7Pe943Ph63/S0f6iy2MJlCbLPxUBKQ0swja4UCi2SC/84gmDUoclgU8hdBjWuSHixXjowCFDSHxBkMqTJAoIUEH9D9K3@0ZSV9IDap6zg98SmjTmKaESVqLY2SzoNyEoOu3w)

Comment: Why did it change to `ð¡` instead of `#` in your last edit? Some special test cases I'm not taking into account?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: Because `#` would fail for single word input outputting the input instead of an empty string.

Comment: Ah yeah, that was it. I remember asking something similar before. I still think `#` should act the same as `ð¡`.. Is there a use-case you can think of where you want to split a string on spaces, but if it doesn't contain a space, it should remain the string (instead of the string wrapped in a list)? Other people reading this; FYI: Using `#` (split on space) on a string without spaces results in the string as is (i.e. `"test" -> "test"`). Using `ð¡` (split on space) on a string without spaces results in the string wrapped in a list (i.e. `"test" -> ["test"]`).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: I think it's mainly due to `#` also being used as `quit if true` (which is its main function). If `#` returned false, you probably wouldn't want the value checked to be wrapped in a list, left on the stack.

Comment: Hmm, you could be right it's related. I always saw `stop loop if true` and `split on space` as two different functions, both using `#`. So the compiler encountering a `#` would do a check: Is an infinite loop running? Yes -> stop it; No -> Split the top of the stack on spaces. If it's implemented like this pseudo-code, it would be strange if `#` as `stop loop if true` would be wrapped in a list, since it would never go into the else-clause in the compiler. But perhaps the pseudo-code isn't so easy to implement in Elixir as I think, in which case you're perhaps right it's related.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: Yeah. `#` can actually be used to exit program outside of loops as well.

Comment: Could you add an explanaton? (I dont know 05AB1E :c)

Comment: Ah ok, didn't knew about that. I always use `q` to exit programs.

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz: Of course. There you go :)

Comment: @KamilDrakari: All answers seem to fail for that atm yes.

Comment: @KamilDrakari: Works now though.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>50 42 58</s> 49 bytes

*-9 bytes thanks to nwellnhof*

```perl6
{~first {m:g/<<./.join~~/^$^a/},[R,] [\~] .words}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ncsxC4JAGIfxvU/xRyISxNsaytZobjWFS@/Ot9Q77hVCRL/61RTOrb@HxynfHkI3YqdxRpgWTZ4HTN3RiCxLRfq01C@LKLelFHOS35IC@X0pkL6tr3kOpw3LEXofyUeFWuko/smFuAExuKF@RKO8XcUrgUxr1@RcZeAk9QOjsraFIS@1VvxFyAr0Qq8w1GD/xxXF4QM)

First option. <s>I'm exploiting the fact the `ord` only returns the ordinal value of first letter of a string, while `chrs` takes a list of ords and returns a string.</s> Or the regex from [moonheart's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/174793/76162) is shorter `:(`. For reference, the previous answer was `.words>>.ord.chrs` instead of `[~] m:g/<<./`

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{~first {m:g/<<./.join~~/^$^a/},[R,] [\~] .words}
{                                               } # Anonymous code block
  first  # Find the first 
                                [R,] [\~] .words  # Of the reverse of the triangular joined words
         {                    }  # That matches:
          m:g/   /   # Match all from the original string
              <<.    # Single letters after a word boundary
                  .join    # Joined
                       ~~/^$^a/   # And starts with the given word
 ~  # And stringify Nil to an empty string
```

Comment: You aren't required to output "IMPOSSIBLE" now

Comment: @Jo King
I can do regexes, but for the life of me I can't seem to think with all the operators. I keep forgetting the x operator exists, for example :P

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, <s>51</s> 48 bytes

Edit: -3 bytes thanks to @xnor.

```
(\w->[r|p<-scanl1(++)w,map(!!0)w==p,r<-p]).words
```

Finds acronym.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcqxCsIwFEbhV/nt1GJbdLfugk6OKnKJTXoxTS5JpA4@u7E4iuPhfAPFe29t1t05l@ep2Z7CSzZNVOTsulwuq6keScrFYlVNXSd12DRyqdrJh1vMI7FDhxkcrijlkY4p7B1a6AqnYmCwsd4XNQoRZSAzT/Enoby3MBxI6/47d/8FWXpyHyH@EdgZkOIb5u/h2AwJicceMVGIxSW/lbZkYm6UyAc)

```
\w->            .words -- let 'w' be the input list split into words
   p<-scanl1(++)w      -- loop 'p' through the list starting with the first word
                       --  and appending the next words one by one, e.g.
                       --  "Fish","is","shiny","hero" -> "Fish","Fishis","Fishisshiny","Fishisshinyhero"
     ,map(!!0)w==p     -- if the word made out of the first characters of the
                       --  words of 'w' equal 'p'
  [r|   r<-p]          -- return the letters of 'p' - if the check before
                       --  never evaluates to True then no letters, i.e. the
                       --  the empty string is returned
```

Comment: Since you're not using `x`, composing `(\w-> ...).words` would be shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 60 bytes

```
^
$'¶
\G(\w)\w* ?
$1
+`^(.+)(\w.*¶\1 )
$1 $2
!`^(.+)(?=¶\1 )
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bclLCoMwFEbheVbxFyz1AYKdF4duIogXG@MFm4Qkxa7MBbixVGgHHXR2@I5XkQ2lc94NqRfZZd@E7HK5FnIt0YqsEdXQ53VVHFaX@yYbFIciu4rTd7S3D6c0M1gv1grnRg1HbGL4bYzWLtDsaZrUv0MLvVgFOPv0bDRo5DuOb2FYzxGRHwohkg9v) Finds the recursive acronym, if any. Explanation:

```
^
$'¶
```

Duplicate the input.

```
\G(\w)\w* ?
$1
```

Reduce the words on the first line to their initial letters.

```
+`^(.+)(\w.*¶\1 )
$1 $2
```

Insert spaces to match the original words, if possible.

```
!`^(.+)(?=¶\1 )
```

Output the first line if it is a prefix of the second line.

Comment: For ppcg paints, output is invalid, it should output nothing since `pp` only spells a portion of the first word, instead of all of it

Comment: @FireCubez Sorry, I was working off an older version of the question.

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, 155, [try it online!](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=3f493af80510e031bd0c7f85f4cd3497)

Selected: Problem 1: Finding acronym

```
type S=String;fn f(t:&str)->S{let l=t.to_lowercase();let w=l.split(' ').fold(S::new(),|a,b|a+&b[..1])+" ";if (l+" ").contains(w.as_str()){w}else{S::new()}}
```

Ungolfed, just a bit:

```
fn f(t: &str) -> String {
    let l = t.to_lowercase();
    let w = l.split(' ').fold(String::new(), |a, b| a + &b[0..1]) + " ";
    if (l + " ").contains(w.as_str()) {
        w
    } else {
        String::new()
    }
}
```

Or if we can assume that the input is all lowercase, just 130:

```
type S=String;fn f(l:S)->S{let w=l.split(' ').fold(S::new(),|a,b|a+&b[..1])+" ";if (l+" ").contains(&w.as_str()){w}else{S::new()}}
```

Comment: Which of the 2 choices does this program do?

Comment: @FireCubez Updated.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 56 bytes

```perl6
$!=[~] m:g{<<.};say $! if m:g{<<\w+}.map({$_ eq $!}).any
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7X1yapODr6OmnoRKvqVD9X0XRNrouViHXKr3axkav1ro4sVJBRVEhMw0qFFOuXauXm1igUa0Sr5BaCJSr1dRLzKv8X/sfAA)

Previously regexes were confusing and unusable to me. Suddenly I understand them perfectly. What happened to me :P

Fulfills choice 1.

Comment: Sadly, I'm still at the stage where regexes are simply madness. Unfortunately, this fails the `ppcgpaints` test, otherwise I would have suggested something like `$!∈.words` for the if condition

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 40 bytes

First option:

```
{$[1=#:x;x;$[(*:t)~,/*:'t:" "\x;*:t;`]]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/Nqlol2tBW2arCusJaJVpDy6pEs05HX8tKvcRKSUEppsIaKGKdEBtb@z9NQSkjUyEzPSc/X4kLyCkoSE5XKEjMzCspRucrJOfn5yikZxYlpqWlQmQ9lf4DAA)

Comment: Which of the 2 options does this work on?

Comment: The first, outputs acronym from string input. I'll edit my post to clarify

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
Ḳµ;\fZḢWƊ
```

A full-program printing the recursive abbreviation if it is possible.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjk2HtlrHpEU93LEo/FjX////CwqS0xUKEjPzSooVkvPzcxTSE3MSKzJTixUK8kuLMvPSFRKTM1MUgPL5Cnn5JQolGakKxdmVAA)**

#### How?

```
Ḳµ;\fZḢWƊ - Main Link: list of characters
Ḳ         - split at space (let's call this v)
 µ        - start a new monadic chain (i.e. f(v)):
   \      - cumulative reduce v with:
  ;       -   concatenation -> [v(1), v(1);v(2), v(1);v(2);v(3); ...]
        Ɗ - last three links as a monad (i.e. f(v)):
     Z    -   transpose -> [[v(1)[1], v(2)[1], ...],[v(1)[1],v(2)[2],...],...]
      Ḣ   -   head -> [v(1)[1], v(2)[1], ...] ... i.e. 'the potential abbreviation'
       W  -   wrap in a list -> ['the potential abbreviation']
    f     - filter discard those from the left list that are not in the right list
          - implicit print -- a list of length 0 prints nothing
          -                   while a list of a single item prints that item
```

Comment: What do you mean by "print the first word"? It needs to find the acronym if one exists, does it do that?

Comment: Fails for "ppcg paints cool galaxies pouring acid into not the sky", should print "ppcg paints" or "ppcgpaints"

Comment: Oh, I missed the adjoining words requirement :(

Comment: Fixed it up to meet this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript [ES6], 74 bytes

```
s=>s.split` `.map(w=>(b+='('+w,e+=')?',t+=w[0]),b=e=t='')&&t.match(b+e)[0]
```

Creates a regular expression to match on.  See examples in code.

All test cases:

```js
let f=

s=>s.split` `.map(w=>(b+='('+w,e+=')?',t+=w[0]),b=e=t='')&&t.match(b+e)[0]

console.log(f('hi igloo'))
// 'hi'.match('(hi(igloo)?)?')[0] == 'hi'

console.log(f('ppcg paints'))
// 'pp'.match('(ppcg(paints)?)?')[0] == ''

console.log(f('ppcg paints cool giraffes'))
// 'ppcg'.match('(ppcg(paints(cool(giraffes)?)?)?)?')[0] == 'ppcg'

console.log(f('ppcg paints cool galaxies pouring acid into night time stars'))
// 'ppcgpaints'.match('(ppcg(paints(cool(galaxies(pouring(acid(into(night(time(stars)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?')[0] == 'ppcgpaints'

console.log(f('ppcg paints cool galaxies pouring acid into night time'))
// 'ppcgpaint'.match('(ppcg(paints(cool(galaxies(pouring(acid(into(night(time)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?')[0] == 'ppcg'

console.log(f('ppcg questions professional pool challengers greatly'))
// 'pqppcg'.match('(ppcg(questions(professional(pool(challengers(greatly)?)?)?)?)?)?')[0] == ''

console.log(f('I'))
// 'I'.match('(I)?')[0] == 'I'

console.log(f('increase i'))
// 'ii'.match('(increase(i)?)?')[0] == ''

console.log(f('i increase'))
// 'ii'.match('(i(increase)?)?')[0] == 'i'
```

Comment: Fail on `increase i`

Comment: @l4m2, now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
⌈:¦$∩h¦↔
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLijIg6wqYk4oipaMKm4oaUIiwiIiwicHBjZyBwYWludHMgY29vbCBnYWxheGllcyBwb3VyaW5nIGFjaWQgaW50byBuaWdodCB0aW1lIl0=)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 106 bytes

First option - finding recursive acronym.
Returns result in list.

```python
I=input().split()
print[' '.join(I[:i])for i in range(1,-~len(I))if[j[0]for j in I]==list(''.join(I[:i]))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5BDoJADEX3nKK7MkaJGlcmHIAzEBYTKEPJONMwNdGNV8chxIWr5re//3156xTDde3jQFAj4trUHOSppamSeM6zkIWDtghYzZFD2bR37swYF2DgAIsNjsrL8fTxlI/G8NjO7bnbDPNmaLq69py0xL8A060ZVxT0oh42/OG2okjvQGzmpbyLHpz19sWUQOIz13Bgex5yqkYI7CYF5QdBUrskLPZ38iSTDfrTe1xWjF8)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 120 bytes

First option - finding recursive acronym.

```python
def F(I,a=[],r=''):
 for j in I.split():
  a+=j,
  if list(''.join(a))==[i[0]for i in I.split()]:r=' '.join(a)
 return r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY1BCoMwFET3nmJ2MVSkdClkW@gZxMVHo35Jk5B8oT29jZuCq2GGmTfxK2vwj@OY7Ixn/WrI9EOTjFK6qzCHhA3s8WpzdCz1GYJuZmuK8gzHWWql2i2wr0lrY3ru78O548tu6AoT/2KFZGVPHumIib2UaxXjuCBScRljCA4LOfqwzYhhL6UFNPJUqBLgeVkFwm@LLJSy0tWVY52NK3lR@vgB)

Comment: You aren't required to output "IMPOSSIBLE" as per @JoKing 's request, that might decrease your byte count

Comment: Single letters like 'I' don't work, it should output that single letter

Comment: @FireCubez fixed

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-apl`, 57 bytes

```ruby
$_=y="";$F.all?{|w|$F.map(&:chr).join[/^#{y+=w}/]?$_=y:p}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY9BCsIwEEX3nmJQEUW0e6V0J3gGURljTEfSTExSatFe3Rh148KVuwf/v8@Mqw9tjMN93ub9/nK4mqPWxe3e3BNWaMejhSjdZH5mMptsN7i107zpsm3xMha2i7EkIKWZe9YKBRbJBP/NIJg1KHJ4OslfCWq8kvRguXZkFKCgI6ScwZAqAwSqJPiA7l/5o11q6QOxSV3H6RKfGHUS04wo09fSKOk8KCcx6La3frB99@MMrX4C)

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 71 bytes

Approach 1

```
l=s=>{p=s.split(' ');k=p.reduce((r,x)=>r+x[0],'');return k==p[0]?k:''}
```

Ungolfed:

```
l=s=>{
    p = s.split(' ');
    k = p.reduce((r,x)=>r+x[0],'');
    return k==p[0] ? k : '';
}
```

- Split the  string by space.
- Create new string by taking first character from each word.
- Compare it with the first word.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 109 bytes

```python
def f(s,J=''.join):s=s.split();return[J(s[:i])for i in range(len(s)+1)if J(zip(*s)[0]).find(J(s[:i]))==0][-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZDBTsMwDIbP21P4lgS6auNYVB6gr1D1ELVJapQ5IXYlxsuXDAkhIXHiZsv@Plt/vsma6GnfF@fBa26GXqn2NSGZjntuOUcUbZ6Lk63QOGgeO5yMTwUQkKBYCk5HR5rN48Wgh0F/YNYPbMbzZFqPtOhvyvT9eRpPl2m/83znR7VWT4gpqeZ4UDnPAbJFEv7dw5xShIDFeu/@mtpo39Ex5LQVpAB2xqWekQSEYRUQvDpgseU/gh/0bXMsmKjul1S/4lrbWOGqmlcbay7BFYZQnJV4@wJRTd3xkKtdgBt1elFNzd3snw)

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 76 bytes

Solution for simple case (acronyms without whitespaces)

```
def^(s:String)={val l=s.split(" ");if(l(0)==l.map(_(0)).mkString)l(0)else""}
```

## Scala, <s>144 bytes</s> 100 bytes (see solution by ASCII-only in the comments)

```
def^(s:String)={val l=s.split(" ");l.scanLeft(List[String]())(_:::List(_)).find(_.mkString==l.map(_(0)).mkString).map(_.mkString).getOrElse("")}
```

Test in REPL

```
scala> def^(s:String)={val l=s.split(" ");if(l(0)==l.map(_(0)).mkString)l(0)else""}
$up: (s: String)String

scala> ^("hi igloo")
res12: String = hi

scala> ^("ppcg paints cool giraffes")
res13: String = ppcg

scala> ^("ppcg paints Xcool giraffes")
res14: String = ""

scala> ^("ppcg paints cool galaxies pouring acid into night time stars")
res15: String = ""

scala>

scala> def^(s:String)={val l=s.split(" ");l.scanLeft(List[String]())(_:::List(_)).find(_.mkString==l.map(_(0)).mkString).map(_.mkString).getOrElse("")}
$up: (s: String)String

scala> ^("hi igloo")
res16: String = hi

scala> ^("ppcg paints cool giraffes")
res17: String = ppcg

scala> ^("ppcg paints Xcool giraffes")
res18: String = ""

scala> ^("ppcg paints cool galaxies pouring acid into night time stars")
res19: String = ppcgpaints
```

Comment: [you are allowed to turn it into a lambda](https://tio.run/##jZDBasMwDEDv/QrhkwwjrNeMDHZYTx097DIYJXiO7WpzbBOpo1D67VmybNDT2Eno6UlIYmuiGfPbu7MCT4YSuJO41DE8lHJefZoBfL05JiuU0/r1WQZK4WYJ@2bk5v48O7HhikskQQVK38WKrUlb5wW3xPLTtketsa3rembYal15Sh22Vf@xCE0Tq94UbPF2Kv5SvbCrPDjZDY@RHSqlL2OZqMSEHtWBgELMWWm9usKl2ABluk4YbM4RAg3Ge8d/eC//FRdveuOJHEPJx3lJMJY6mOoZEoWDgFDvgMUM36Mu4xc)

Comment: Can `:::` be replaced with `++`? Also, `List[String]` -> `Seq[Any]`?

Comment: [100?](https://tio.run/##jZBBS0MxDMfv@xShpxakzKtSwYPeZAcvgsiofW0X7UtLk8lg7LM/33wgO4mnkF9@CX/CwRc/1fePGASePBLEg0QaGO5bO66@fId087inIFjp@vVZOlK@Wsqbm9jdHc9OcWy5FRStQJnbYpFQ2CakQW/t@LksOFfs6Jve6rUxv9Qs7KLPUTb9oXDUSpnT1GYqhXTSaoeAudSqjFld4NZChjanF4ZQa4GM3acU@Q/v5b/i4s1vOmBkaHV/Dgk@4ADzvAJh3gkIjhFYfP85dZq@AQ)

Comment: @ASCII-only, cool! This solution beats Python. :)

Comment: Mind adding the code sometime? IMO it's a bit weird seeing the bytecount without seeing the solution

Comment: wait. it's invalid

Comment: it should just not add the current word if the next word doesn't match

Comment: [110](https://tio.run/##jZDBSgQxDIbv@xShpxakuFdlBA/uTTx4WEFkqZ22E@2kpcnKwrLPPs46IHsSTyFfvgT@sHfZTeX9I3iBR4cE4SCBeob7Wo@rL9cg3mz25AULrV@fpSGlq6W8dRN3d8ezkzu2XDOKVqDMbbZIKGwjUq@zHV3VO31tjB0/l1VgcU14izLA7peaxbzoU5Cn9pA5aKXMaaozlUw6ajUgYMqlKGNWF7hWn6DOOYTBl5IhYXMxBv7De/mvuHjzww4YGGrZ/0RxHnuY5wUI0yAgOIbzkdP0DQ)

Comment: The output for 4th test case in your second solution should be "" and not `ppcg`. On the other hand, your first solution looks correct to me.

Comment: Nope, see the testcases in the question

Comment: Right, I double checked test cases. However that's a bit misleading given the definition in a starting post "a sentence is a recursive acronym if the first letters of **each** of the words spell out the first word or words".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87825/discussion-between-ascii-only-and-dr-y-wit).